# Create s3 bucket policy for multiple existing s3 bucket using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I have some S3 buckets which are created using terraform code as below:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "a" {
  ...
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  ...
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "c" {
  ...
}
```

Now I want to create bucket policy and apply this policy for all existing s3 bucket (a, b, c). How can I get s3 bucket id and do a loop or something like that? Please advise me more. Thanks a lot!!!

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "abc" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.*.id
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create multiple buckets which just different by one or few arguments (e.g. name), you should be using [count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html) or [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html) and provide the names as `list`. For example:

```
variable "buckets" {
    default = ["a", "b", "c"]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  for_each = var.buckets
  name     = each.key
  # ...
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "abc" {
  for_each = var.buckets
  bucket   = aws_s3_bucket.bucket[each.key].id
  ...
}
```

**Update**

You can also do:

```
locals {
    buckets = [aws_s3_bucket.a, aws_s3_bucket.b, ws_s3_bucket.c]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "abc" {
  for_each = {for idx, bucket in local.buckets: idx => bucket}

  bucket = each.value.id
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, I know this solution but I don't want change anything relate to existing s3 bucket. Is there another way to resolve my case?

Comment: @DươngQuangThọ I updated then answer to iterate over existing buckets.

Comment: @DươngQuangThọ No problem. Glad it worked out.